# Dual-boot issues

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Pretty new to the stuff still. I dual-boot windows10 with ubuntu 20.04. About 3 weeks ago I had start having issues where It'd boot me into win10, not into GRUB. Running a x64 system. I had tried scannow and repairing with DISM. Then even trying bcdedit to set the {bootmgr} path. Unfortunately...that hasn't working either. Checking BIOS. Everything had seemed fine as well. Would anyone know anything about this. Thank you!

Comment: you can try `boot-repair` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Just boot up from USB flash drive and install boot-repair and repair your grub :)).

Comment: This shouldn't cause any issues or loose anything right?

Comment: no, it will not, just use the recommended repair and it will tell you the steps also this might help you https://askubuntu.com/a/182863/1112104.

Comment: Double  check UEFI settings. You had to change some when instlaling Ubuntu. And  Windows may have done an UEFI update which would reset many settings back to defaults. If Boot-Repair does not resolve issue, post the link to its Summary Report.

Comment: Hey! I'm finally able to be signed back in! I tried many things now up to this point. Using repair-boot which says it completed, still didn't work. I'll past the pastebin below. I tried bcdedit with grubx64.efi , didn't worth. Tried with debain32 just for the hell of it. Then tried with shimx64.efi, also didn't work.

Boot order seems to be fine. Legacy support is enabled, secure boot disabled. Still nothing at all.

[Repair File](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QhQTfpqVNd/)